# graphql_flutter Error: The non-abstract class 'GraphQLWebSocketChannel' is missing implementations

Tags: flutter, stacked, graphql-flutter, flutter-stacked

I am trying to use graphql_flutter (https://pub.dev/packages/graphql_flutter) for my MVVM architecture. (https://stacked.filledstacks.com/docs/getting-started/overview) I got this error below from the package graphql_flutter when I try to run my code

`../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/graphql-5.1.2/lib/src/links/websocket_link/websocket_client.dart:577:7: Error: The non-abstract class 'GraphQLWebSocketChannel' is missing implementations for these members:

- WebSocketChannel.ready
  Try to either
- provide an implementation,
- inherit an implementation from a superclass or mixin,
- mark the class as abstract, or
- provide a 'noSuchMethod' implementation.

class GraphQLWebSocketChannel extends StreamChannelMixin<dynamic>
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/web_socket_channel-2.3.0/lib/src/channel.dart:56:22: Context: 'WebSocketChannel.ready' is defined here.
final Future<void> ready = Future.value();`

This is my code in the main.dart file. I am getting the error as long as I have imported the package.

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:testing/app/app.locator.dart';
    import 'package:testing/ui/common/app_colors.dart';
    import 'package:testing/ui/setup/setup_bottom_sheet_ui.dart';
    import 'package:testing/ui/setup/setup_dialog_ui.dart';
    import 'package:stacked_services/stacked_services.dart';

    import 'package:graphql_flutter/graphql_flutter.dart';

    import 'app/app.router.dart';

    void main() {
      setupLocator();
      setupDialogUi();
      setupBottomSheetUi();

      runApp(const MyApp());
    }

    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        HttpLink httpLink = HttpLink("https://api.github.com/graphql");

        AuthLink authLink = AuthLink(
          getToken: () async => 'Bearer PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN',
        );

        Link link = authLink.concat(httpLink);

        ValueNotifier<GraphQLClient> qlClient = ValueNotifier(
          GraphQLClient(
            link: link,
            // The default store is the InMemoryStore, which does NOT persist to disk
            cache: GraphQLCache(store: HiveStore()),
          ),
        );

        return GraphQLProvider(
            client: qlClient,
            child: MaterialApp(
              title: 'Flutter Demo',
              theme: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
                primaryColor: kcBackgroundColor,
                focusColor: kcPrimaryColor,
                textTheme: Theme.of(context).textTheme.apply(
                      bodyColor: Colors.black,
                    ),
              ),
              initialRoute: Routes.startupView,
              onGenerateRoute: StackedRouter().onGenerateRoute,
              navigatorKey: StackedService.navigatorKey,
              navigatorObservers: [
                StackedService.routeObserver,
              ],
            ));
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I got this error yesterday. I added it to the pubspec.yaml wrote the following lines and it worked for me

```
dependency_overrides:
  web_socket_channel: 2.2.0
```

link - https://github.com/flutter/cocoon/pull/2405 (go to the section "Files changed")

Answer (score 1):

Just upgrade to:

```
dependencies:
  graphql_flutter: ^5.1.2
```

they already updated their viersions
https://github.com/zino-hofmann/graphql-flutter/commit/f702ff12040834997d7fdbb844e618ec85756589