# Flutter graphql/graphql_flutter package throwing : The non-abstract class 'GraphQLWebSocketChannel' is missing implementations

Tags: flutter, graphql, cross-platform, flutter-dependencies

I have a project that i am trying to connect to graphql API in flutter and I have tried installing the graphql flutter package and i am getting the below error when i attempt building the project. I have tried playing the sdk versions but all the same error

```
 Writing result bundle at path:
    /var/folders/71/5s_xdvm50d1bcj4q8zf_41j40000gp/T/flutter_tools.l4Y5sf/flutter_ios_build_temp_dir1J1YUm/t
    emporary_xcresult_bundle

../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/graphql-5.1.2/lib/src/links/websocket_link/websocket_cli
ent.dart:577:7: Error: The non-abstract class 'GraphQLWebSocketChannel' is missing implementations for
these members:
 - WebSocketChannel.ready
Try to either
 - provide an implementation,
 - inherit an implementation from a superclass or mixin,
 - mark the class as abstract, or
 - provide a 'noSuchMethod' implementation.

class GraphQLWebSocketChannel extends StreamChannelMixin<dynamic>
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/web_socket_channel-2.3.0/lib/src/channel.dart:56:22:
Context: 'WebSocketChannel.ready' is defined here.
  final Future<void> ready = Future.value();
                     ^^^^^
Failed to package /Users/nazehabel/mobile-projects/aysquared.
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
note: Building targets in dependency order
```

my install version is `graphql-5.1.1` and I keep seeing it referenced error from the `graphql-5.1.2` version and it's the same thing happening for `graphql_flutter: ^5.1.0` which throws the same error referencing the `graphql_flutter: ^5.1.2` from my local cache pubspec and i was wondering what i need to change to get one of them work with the right version not referencing a different cache version.

Below is my pubspec.yaml

```
description: A new Flutter project.

module:
  androidX: true
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

version: 1.0.0

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.17.5 <4.0.0'
  flutter: '>=2.5.3 <3.0.0'
dependencies:
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  dio: ^4.0.6
  file_picker: ^5.2.4
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_dotenv: ^5.0.2
  flutter_riverpod: ^2.0.2
  flutter_screenutil: ^5.6.0
  flutter_secure_storage: ^7.0.1
  flutter_smart_dialog: ^4.8.0
  flutter_spinkit: ^5.1.0
  flutter_svg: ^1.1.6
  freezed: ^2.2.1
  freezed_annotation: ^2.2.0
  get_it: ^7.2.0
  hooks_riverpod: ^2.1.1
  image_picker: ^0.8.6
  intl: ^0.17.0
  intl_phone_number_input: ^0.7.1
  oktoast: ^3.3.1
  provider: ^6.0.5
  riverpod_annotation: ^1.0.4
  sliding_up_panel: ^2.0.0+1
  timer_count_down: ^2.2.1
  url_launcher: ^6.1.7
  visibility_detector: ^0.3.3
  syncfusion_flutter_charts: ^20.4.42
  syncfusion_localizations: ^20.4.42
  desktop_window: ^0.4.0
  localization: ^2.1.0
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  fl_chart: ^0.55.2
  percent_indicator: ^4.2.2
  charts_flutter: ^0.12.0
  pinput: ^2.2.21
  google_fonts: ^3.0.1
  dropdown_button2: ^1.9.2
  dotted_line: ^3.1.0
  flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.6.2
  trash_themes: ^0.0.2
  graphql: ^5.1.1
  graphql_flutter: ^5.1.0


flutter_native_splash:
  android: true
  ios: true
  image: assets/images/logo-white.png
  android_gravity: center
  ios_content_mode: center
  color: "#FFFFFF"

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  build_runner: ^2.3.2
  riverpod_generator: ^1.0.4
  flutter_native_splash: ^2.1.6
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
flutter:

 
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    # - assets/images
    - .env
    - assets/images/
    - assets/images/categories_images/
    - assets/images/grocery_images/
    - assets/images/beverages_images/
    - assets/icons/
    - assets/icons/account_icons/
    - assets/fonts/

  fonts:
    - family: Gilroy
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/gilroy/Gilroy-Regular.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/gilroy/Gilroy-SemiBold.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/gilroy/Gilroy-Bold.otf
```

I have tried following the solution here [graphql_flutter Error: The non-abstract class 'GraphQLWebSocketChannel' is missing implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75315470/graphql-flutter-error-the-non-abstract-class-graphqlwebsocketchannel-is-missi) and `pod deintegrate`,`pod install`, `flutter clean`, `flutter pub cache repair`, etc and none of it didn't work for me either